# Limit Eloquent Model to specific columns

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I'm pulling from a rather large database and for security reasons, my database user can only select a limited number of columns from the student table: name, graduation_date, and gender. But there are dozens of other columns returned in a select * statement.

In regular SQL, if I run something like:

```
SELECT * FROM students
```

will return an error on that table.  Same if I run the eloquent model

```
Students::all();
```

will return an error as well.

I know in Eloquent, you can limit your selects when defining a relationship similar to:

```
class Students extends Eloquent {

    protected $table        = 'student_info';

    public function classes() {
        return $this->hasMany('classes')->select(array('room', 'time'));
    }

}
```

So, My question is, can the select limits be done on the main model, similar to limiting it on the classes table.  So, when I run `Student::all();` it only selects the columns I need.

The main problem is every time I run a student Query, I'm having to do a specific select command each time instead of just saying "`Student::all()`".  Same thing for Student::find(1); will also return an error, because it still runs a `SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE id = 1`.

I tried setting `$visible` variable, but it still renders sql equivalent to `SELECT * FROM ...`

Anyone have a solution?

**UPDATE:**
Please note that I'm looking or a solution on the model level, not the controller level.  I can select from the controller side, but that defeats the purpose of a Model concept and have to declare the columns to select at every query.

Thanks!
Troy

Comment: You can use global scope for default select clause - http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#global-scopes. And always you can select needed columns with `select` or in `get($columns)`, `find($id, $columns)`, `all($columns)` and so on.

Comment: @jarek, I'll look into the scopes. I'm trying to keep this at the model level and not the controller level. Otherwise, it's defeating  the purpose of what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically having to declare the columns for every query, which is not ideal

Comment: You can create your own intermediate custom class, overload the `all()`, and add a protected array that contains the returnable columns. I'll make an answer right now.

Comment: @Kousha You don't need that, just use global scopes.  @ Troy - this is exactly why I suggest that solution. Adjusting every query makes no sense, thus apply a scope and all the queries for given model will use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an intermediate class and overload the `all()` function. Let's call this class `Elegant`

**Elegant.php**

```
abstract class Elegant extends Model
{
    public static $returnable = [];

    public function all()
    {
        return $this->get(static::$returnable)->all();
    }
}
```

Then you extend this class, and define your returnable columns to it.

**Student.php**

```
<?php
class Student extends Elegant
{
    public static $returnable = ['room', 'time'];
}
```

Now use it as you wanted: `Student::all()` in your controller. If you leave `returnable` as an empty array, then you will get everything.

Comment: `all` is static function, you'd rather override `get`, but definitely this is not the way to got.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Jarek's suggestion of using Global Scope you could do it like this, I'm not 100% sure the remove part is right though, will need testing.

**SelectLimitTrait.php**

```
trait SelectLimitTrait {

    public static function bootSelectLimitTrait()
    {    
        static::addGlobalScope(new SelectLimitScope);
    }

    public function getQueryable()
    {
        if(! $this->queryable ) return array('*');

        return $this->queryable;
    }  

}
```

**SelectLimitScope.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;

class SelectLimitScope implements ScopeInterface {

    public function apply(Builder $builder)
    {
        $query = $builder->getQuery();

        $queryable = $builder->getModel()->getQueryable();

        $query->columns = $queryable;
    }

    public function remove(Builder $builder)
    {
        $query = $builder->getQuery();

        $query->columns = null;
    }

}
```

And then in your Eloquent model put this:

**Students.php**

```
class Students extends \Eloquent  {

    use SelectLimitTrait;

    protected $queryable = array('name','graduation_date', 'gender');

}
```

Now `Students::all()` and `Students::find(1)` etc. are limited to querying name, graduation_date and gender

Answer (score 3):

You may use something like this:

```
public function newQuery()
{
    return parent::newQuery()->select('room', 'time');
}
```

Put the `newQuery` method in your `Students` model and use the `Student` model normally you would use. It's a hacky way but easiest one.  Just override the `parent::query()`. In this way you'll always get the selected fields.

Comment: Thanks Alpha, I'm returning an error right now, but I think that's an error further in my code.